# How to get Rownumber to display when using hide or show columns with an expression-SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008. I am hiding some of the rows based on condition.

I want to display the row number for the filtered row. I have created a column and added expression to that column as RowNumber(Nothing).

Problem:

It is displaying value for row number without filtering.

For example I get 2,7,9,10 etc. As these are the columns from the original Query they are displayed.

I just want the serial number for the displayed records.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the rows rather than hiding them. When you hide them they are still process just invisible. When you filter them they are not processed at all.